# Smart Pointer behavior using *

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have the following code snippet:

```
QList<const GLMeshPtr*> meshList;
m_itemsList->getSelectedMeshes(meshList);

for (auto m : meshList)
{
    if (GLBodyPtr c = (*m)->getStandard()) {
        c->executeMeshFix();
    }
}
```

`GLMeshPtr` is set as in this `typedef`:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<GLMesh> GLMeshPtr;
```

The definition of `m_itemsList->getSelectedMeshes` is:

```
void QMeshList::getSelectedMeshes(QList<const GLMeshPtr*>& list)
{
    for (auto& m : m_meshList) {
        if (m->isSelected()) {
            list.push_back(m->getGLMesh());
        }
    }
}
```

Definition for `getGLMesh` is:

```
const GLMeshPtr* getGLMesh() const { return &m_glmesh; } // where m_glmesh is a GLMeshPtr.
```

My question is very simple, yet, I couldn't find any reference to it. Does the `*` keyword create a copy of the value in the stack, necessarily, or does it use the value "in place"?

I talk more specifically about this line:

```
if (GLBodyPtr c = (*m)->getStandard()) {
```

Am I creating unnecessary copies of GLBodyPtr? I don't want anyone here to share the pointer.

Comment: `*m` would be `const GLMeshPtr&`, so no copy.

Comment: Also, are you sure you wanted a list of pointers to smart pointers? That seems like a very strange thing to want.

Comment: It's a `shared_ptr`. Sorry. Yes. I'm sending back a list of pointers to smart pointers because sending the smart points themselves is heavy. Even if I move them instead of copying it creates too much hassle to do so every function call.

Comment: Or is there a better way of dealing with a list of smart pointers?

Comment: If you never copy a `shared_ptr`, why not replace it with `unique_ptr`? You can return a *non-owning* (raw) pointer from `getGLMesh`

Comment: Because I will sometimes want to create a copy of the `shared_ptr`, but that's exceptional behavior for that method. I want to enforce the caller to explicitly copy the `shared_ptr` if they want to.

Comment: @Alexandre Severino Did you profile this? Sounds not really likely that the copy of a smart-ptr is the bottleneck if you do operations on meshes. Especially if the solution to the problem is pushing to a list.

Comment: I'm not currently trying to fix any performance problem. My code is at the beginning of development and I just want it to be as optimized as possible everywhere I can make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the * operator returns a reference, i.e. `GLBodyPtr const&`. It is `const` because the pointer is declared to point to a const object. See definition of `std::shared_ptr::operator*` on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*).

References are basically like pointers that can't be changed once they're initialized, so it's not a copy of the `shared_ptr` object.